# how to print on a remote printer

Tags: printing

I need to print a file, from my android device, to a remote printer online on the university network. The printer has a static IP and a hostname visible on internet.

Tried: on the "settings" app chosen "service" then "print". Add printer, then try to add a printer via Ip and/or hostname. Does not work.

Comment: Do you know the model of the printer, the installed printer services on the Android device, and whether the printer is compatible with the printer services?

Comment: I would like to know a general procedure, we have a lot of printers at the university, hopefully I found one that is supported, but till now, when I put the IP I get the message "no printer found" which sounds different from "printer not supportet" or similar

Comment: I just went on "settings -> connected devices -> Print and I had a "default print service"